# convert number to list of char

Tags: sql, postgresql, for-loop, plpgsql

I have a function who should return  a letter list of alphabet.
I obtain a table with correct size with nothing inside.
My code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION p_get_list(IN nb integer)
RETURNS TABLE(strconcat text) AS
$BODY$DECLARE
i integer;
j integer;
r integer;
strconc text;

BEGIN
    j=ASCII('A');
    FOR i IN 1..nb LOOP
        r=j+i-1;
        SELECT chr(r) INTO strconc;
        RETURN NEXT;
    END LOOP;
end if;

END;$BODY$
```

Thanks.

Comment: is it what you try to do: `select chr(a) from generate_series(ascii('A'),ascii('A')+25,1) a;` ?..

Comment: Yes exactly thanks!

Comment: No because the lenght series could be different and lenght is bixed by nb.so i replace 25 by nb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can reuse existing function `generate_series` for it, eg:

```
t=# select chr(a) from generate_series(ascii('A'),ascii('A')+25,1) a;
 chr
-----
 A
 B
 C
 D
 E
 F
 G
 H
 I
 J
 K
 L
 M
 N
 O
 P
 Q
 R
 S
 T
 U
 V
 W
 X
 Y
 Z
(26 rows)
```